# Tastypie get latest record

Tags: tastypie

Instead of returning multiple objects when the ID isn't set. I'd like it to return only one, the latest.

```
# return latest entry
/api/entry/
{'id': 2, 'foo': 'bar', ...}

# return specified entry
/api/entry/1/
{'id': 1, 'foo': 'bar', ...}
```

I've tried overriding both `obj_get_list` and `get_object_list`, but neither worked for me.

Do I need to create a view for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using aniav's solution, and adding the necessary modifications:

```
Resource
    class Meta:
         max_limit=1
    get_object_list(self,request):
        return super(self, Resource).get_object_list(request).filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date')
```

where of course date could be replaced with the field for which you want the latest of.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how have you tried overriding `obj_get_list` but basically what you have to do is define it in your `Resource` like this:

```
def get_object_list(self, request):
    return super(self, Resource).get_object_list(request)[:1]
```

You could also append `latest('somedate')` if you haven't set ordering on the date field by default.

Comment: That's what I did and I get `'User' object has no attribute 'filter'`. I assume that is because `get_object_list` needs to return a list of querysets. Slicing or using `latest` only produces one.

Comment: Ah right, it's because of this here:
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L2125

Ok, so you need to slice the results at a later stage. You could define the paginator limit (and set it to 1) in resource meta or override `get_list` method.